# Microsoft.SharePointUpgrade.SPUpgradeException error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, configuration-wizard, update, exception

I installed sharepoint upgrade "KB3115293" to be able to restore a site collection created in  another farm with the same version.
After the installation, I excuted sharepoint configuration wizard in both sharepoint machines and every thing went well (Successful configuration).
after that I configured distributed cache service (it worked after a long time and lot of tries)
But now when I execute Sharepoint configuration wizard, i get this error message :

[image]

It said that : the configuration failed with Microsoft.SharePointUpgrade.SPUpgradeException (one or more types failed to load)

and I got these details from log files :

```
Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
04/27/2017 10:08:08.97  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPSiteWssSequence   ajywy   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=SharePoint_AdminContent_5e12b17f-6668-48d... 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:08.97  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPSiteWssSequence   ajywy   ERROR   Failed to call GetTypes()   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:08.99  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPSiteWssSequence   ajywy   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=SharePoint_AdminContent_5e12b17f-6668-48d... 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:08.99  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPSiteWssSequence   ajywy   ERROR   Exception: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.02  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnp   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=SharePoint_AdminContent_5e12b17f-6668-48d... 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.02  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnp   ERROR   Grow [SPTree Value=SPContentDatabase Name=SharePoint_AdminContent_5e12...] failed.  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.04  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnp   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=SharePoint_AdminContent_5e12b17f-6668-48d... 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.04  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnp   ERROR   Exception: Échec de chargement d'un ou plusieurs types. Veuillez consulter le journal de mise à niveau pour plus de détails.    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.04  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnp   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=SharePoint_AdminContent_5e12b17f-6668-48d... 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.04  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnp   ERROR      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.LoadUpgradeActions()     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_Actions()     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_ActionsInternal()     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUtility.GetLatestTargetSchemaVersionBeforeMajorVersion(Type typeActionSequence, Int32 majorVer)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSiteSequence.get_PreviousTargetSchemaVersion()     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.PopulateSequencesTable(StringBuilder sqlstr, Boolean siteSequence)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ConstructSiteNeedsUpgradeQuery(Guid siteId)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.GetSiteNeedsUpgrade(SPUpgradeSession session, SPContentDatabase database, Dictionary`2& dictSitesNeedUpgrade, Dictionary`2& dictSitesNeedFeatureUpgrade)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.AddNextLevelObjects()     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root, Boolean bRecursing, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.21  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoi   INFO    No context object   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.21  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoi   ERROR   SPManager.InplaceUpgradeAdministrationWebApplication failed.    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.22  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoi   INFO    No context object   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.22  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoi   ERROR   Exception: Échec de chargement d'un ou plusieurs types. Veuillez consulter le journal de mise à niveau pour plus de détails.    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.24  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoi   INFO    No context object   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/27/2017 10:08:09.24  PSCONFIG (0x0D34)   0x04B8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPManager   ajxoi   ERROR      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.LoadUpgradeActions()     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_Actions()     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_ActionsInternal()     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUtility.GetLatestTargetSchemaVersionBeforeMajorVersion(Type typeActionSequence, Int32 majorVer)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSiteSequence.get_PreviousTargetSchemaVersion()     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.PopulateSequencesTable(StringBuilder sqlstr, Boolean siteSequence)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ConstructSiteNeedsUpgradeQuery(Guid siteId)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.GetSiteNeedsUpgrade(SPUpgradeSession session, SPContentDatabase database, Dictionary`2& dictSitesNeedUpgrade, Dictionary`2& dictSitesNeedFeatureUpgrade)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.AddNextLevelObjects()     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root, Boolean bRecursing, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabase.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Upgrade>b__0()     à Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunAsUser(SPUserToken userToken, Boolean bResetContext, WaitCallback code, Object param)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.InplaceUpgradeAdministrationWebApplication()   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Any idea how to fix this error ??

Comment: How many server is your farm? Wat does the server status page say? Please rerun the SharePoint Products  Configuration Wizard (GUI) again. Often it fails the first time, but succeeds the second time.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the SP cache folders? Download the PowerShell script from https://spcachecleaner.codeplex.com/ and execute it. Don't worry, it is safe to execute as it is.

Comment: TempaC : we have 3 servers: application server, web server and database server and I have this problem with the web server after having some troubles configuring distributed cache service. and I reran the configuration wizzard several times and it's always the same error that appears

Comment: Mihail Popa : It didn't work :(